# Best Way to Use Back-to-Back if Statements That Rely on the Same Variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I am working on a script that streams real time data and appends it to numpy arrays. If the array is a certain length, I will use it as a trigger to perform another action. However I noticed sometimes they cancel one and other. To give an example:

```
if len(closeBidArray) > 20:
    execution_logic()   

if len(closeBidArray) > 1:  
    # spreadsheet_append 
    data = "%s" % (closeBidArray[-1])
    ayTools.spreadsheet_append(fileName, data)  

closeBidArray = np.append(closeBidArray, bidPrice)
```

Given the example above, so long as closeBidArray is less than 20 it does not trigger the execution logic, but does do spreadsheet_append and appends to the numpy array (as seen in the last line above). However, if the length of closeBidArray is greater than 20, that when it refuses to perform spreadsheet_append nor will it append to numpy array, despite the fact that both of those tasks are set to take place after. Any ideas on where I am going astray? Thanks

Comment: why wouldn't spreadsheet_append run when length of closeBidArray is greater than 20?

Comment: I'm guessing you got something weird going on in execution_logic() and your program is terminating before evaluating your second if statement.

Comment: @BobHaffner, execution_logic() basically does some math to see if the avg. is less than some other number, and then prints. Nothing too detrimental.

Comment: Have you stepped thru the code with a debugger to verify if the 2nd if is being evaluated?

Comment: @BobHaffner, sorry I'm a bit of a beginner at this, how would I go about doing that (could I just include a print statement)?

Comment: Yes, a print statement between the two IF statements would suffice.  Perhaps one that prints the length of your array

Comment: @BobHaffner, sorry for the late response (the script uses real-time data) but you were right it was a problem with execution_logic(), apparently there was a parameter it could not access from inside the class.